# How can I clone my installation to a btrfs partition and make it bootable?

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, rsync, cp

I'm trying to copy all files, configuration, everything, to a new btrfs partition without reinstalling.

So far, what I've tried is to go to a live cd session (which is actually booted from an iso on a separate partition) and use `rsync` to copy everything from the primary partition to the new one. Then update the new `fstab` to have the new UUID. Then finally `update-grub`.

This seems to work, everything copies correctly with the correct permissions and ownership, grub makes a new menu entry for the new partition, and trying to boot it even seems to work! The problem is that it's still booting to the old partition. Even if I choose the new menu entry on boot up.

I've also tried all of that, but replace `rsync` with `cp -a`.

**Edit**

Here's the `fstab` files for both the old and new partitions.

Old fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
UUID=11a64844-0379-4d5c-8e2a-e06ff3f79619 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=C040-6244  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile swap swap defaults 0 0
UUID=f4f71706-d44b-42a4-8617-50eed11c5650 /boot/recovery ext4 ro 0 0
```

New fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
UUID=1b77a06a-efb7-4717-bfb7-9f725aa50f42 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=C040-6244  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile swap swap defaults 0 0
UUID=f4f71706-d44b-42a4-8617-50eed11c5650 /boot/recovery ext4 ro 0 0
```

The `/boot/recovery` in here is the iso partition I mentioned earlier.

Comment: Remove, your old hhd and try to reboot.  Is it working?

Comment: @Aravind It's the same physical disk, just different partitions. Specifically, the old one is /dev/sda2 and the new one is /dev/sda4. I don't want to delete /dev/sda2

Comment: I think I miss understood. Shall we have content of your fstab in your question? Could you please edit and  include fstab file content  in your question?

Comment: @Aravind I've added the `fstab`s, though I'd like to mention that the new partition is actually ext4 for right now. I wanted to perfect cloning before I tried doing it to a new filesystem. I asked the question about btrfs because that's my end goal.

Comment: Interesting.  last try, you have efi portition. lets temp try to disable uefi and check is uefi is the root of problem. This is only for checking.

Comment: @Aravind I enabled legacy boot mode in my BIOS (that is what you meant, right?) and it seemed to not want to boot in legacy mode. It tries, then tries to boot with PXE, then power cycles and boots back up with UEFI.